# Regex Simple Multiline Question

Tags: python, regex

```
pattern = '^([R][uU][nN])(.*)\((.*)\).'
```

Essentially what I am trying to do with this is find procedure calls in the data I have in the form:

```
RUN proc-name-can-be-anything (input parameters, input, output).
```

can also be:

```
RUN proc-name-long
                  ( 
                    input parameter,
                    other parameter,
                    one_more_just_because 
                  ).
```

The pattern works fine for any single line instances, I need to be able to accommodate multi-line and have been tearing my hair out as I dive back into python and regular expressions (I know the pattern is only for single line at the moment because "." cannot be a newline). All I really care about is the parameters of the procedure call I am looking at.

Thanks

Comment: Does this concern Python regex specifically?

Comment: Yes this is Python regex specifically

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.S
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL

> Make the `'.'` special character match any character at all, including a newline

And you can include this in your regex by prepending the pattern string with `'(?s)'`

Also, don't forget that you might want to use the raw string syntax with pattern strings, just in case. I don't think you'll have any problems with your example as given, but it's always a good idea to use them just as a self-reminder.

So something like `pattern = r'(?s)^([R][uU][nN])(.*)\((.*)\).'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

ss = '''RUN proc-name ( input parameter,
                        other parameter,
                        one_more_just_because ).'''

regx = re.compile('^(R[Uu][Nn]) +(.+?) *\((.*?)\)\.',re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

print regx.search(ss).groups()
```

If you don't want to use re.DOTALL, you can also do:

```
import re

ss = '''RUN proc-name ( input parameter,
                        other parameter,
                        one_more_just_because ).'''


regx = re.compile('^(R[Uu][Nn]) +(.+?) *\(([\s\S]*?)\)\.',re.MULTILINE)

print regx.search(ss).groups()
```